# cannot add linqpad.exe to global cache

Tags: .net, linqpad

i am trying to add MongoDb Linqpad Driver via NoRM. I am following instructions as in http://normlinqpaddriver.codeplex.com/
however i cannot add it.

i get the following

C:\Program Files\LinQPad>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\gacutil.ex
e /i LINQPAd.exe

Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 1.1.4318.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2002. All rights reserved.

Failure adding assembly to the cache: Unknown Error

i am running linqpad v 2.26.2

Comment: I'd wouldn't recommend adding LINQPad to the GAC - this will cause problems when LINQPad updates itself. You should never need to add LINQPad to the GAC - there was an assembly resolution issue with third-party drivers in earlier versions that could be hacked around by GACing LINQPad - but this was fixed in v2.26 / v4.26.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have .NET version issues, the LinqPad verision  2.26.2 you are using is for .NET 3.5 and the MongoDb LinqPad Driver uses 4.0.

---

Other potential issues I see:  You are using the gacutil that was provided with 2003?  You need to be using at least the one that came with 2008.

Open up a Visual Studio command prompt 2008 and you should something like see..

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC>gacutil
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 3.5.21022.8
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.`

---

Once you move to 4.0 you need to use the gacutil that is in:

`C:\Program File
s\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin`